# Transfer JavaScript Array to PHP array using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to transfer a list of data from a javascript array to a php array and I can't seem to get ajax to do the trick.  Can someone show me the code on how to do this?  So far here is what I have, which is just the array:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var dates;
// the dates array is then filled up here
// it contains information in the form {'2012-01-01', '2012-03-12', ...}

$.ajax({        
   type: "REQUEST",
   url: "NAMEOFPHPFILE.php",
   data: { sendData1 : dates },
   success: function() {
        alert("Attempting to transfer array -> AJAX");        
   }
}); 

var submissions;
// the submissions array is then filled up here
// it contains information in the form {int, int, ...}

// ect ......... with 3 more arrays using { sendData2 : submissions },
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$bDates = $_REQUEST['sendData1']; 
// need to set this array = to the JavaScript dates array
$bSubmissions = $_REQUEST['sendData2'];
// need to set this array = to the JavaScript submissions array
?>
```

I would prefer to use the REQUEST method to prevent information logging into the URL.  **This code also doesn't work when trying POST instead of REQUEST**

At the very end of the .php page, I am outputting a bunch of arrays onto a CSV page where I iterate through the arrays and place their elements in the file.  This already works, but I need to transfer some of these arrays from javascript to PHP so that I can spit out the data.  That looks like this:

```
<?php


$stringData = "Dates, Number of Lines Changed, , Bug Dates, Arrivals, Fixed, Closed, Hold_";
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dataXAxis); $i++){
        $date = substr($_REQUEST['Dates'][$i+1], 0, 24);
        $stringData .= "$date, $dataYAxis[$i], , $bDates[$i], $bSubmissions[$i], $bCompletions[$i], $bDones[$i], $bRejections[$i]_";
}


echo '<BR><BR><a href="download_csv.php?csv=' . $stringData . '" target="_blank">Download Your CSV File</a>';
?>
```

Why doesn't the AJAX work?  The arrays appear empty...

Comment: What do you get when you use `var_dump($_REQUEST)`? C'mon, that's basic debugging!

Comment: You need to use jquery post - then request the variables via php.  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: `json_encode()` is a php function you should investigate.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to try sending the data in the form of JSON. Then using json_decode, you can convert it to an array. Example:

```
   var Json = {"User1":"John", "User2":"Joe", "User3","Jerry"};
   var data = "data="+Json;
   hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
           console.log(hr.responseText);
       }
   }
   hr.open("POST", "parsefile.php", true);
   hr.send(data);
```

Then when you get the data in your PHP file it's something like:

```
 $data = $_POST['data'];
 $array = json_decode($data, true);
```

This all will tell php to turn our data into an assosciative array. It can then be manipulated as an assosciative array.

Answer (score 1):

I was literally just working on this.

jQuery

```
var group_ids = $('.form-elements li').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('group-id')
}).get()

$.get('{{ url('group/update_order_by') }}', {group_ids: group_ids});
```

PHP from the restful Laravel framework

```
public function get_update_order_by()
{
    $group_ids = Input::get("group_ids");
    $group_count = count($group_ids);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $group_count; ++$i) {
        $group = Group::find($group_ids[$i] );
        $group->order_by = $i;
        $group->save();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Raw PHP (ugh...)

```
    $group_ids = $_GET("group_ids");
    $group_count = count($group_ids);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $group_count; ++$i) {
        echo $group_ids[$i];
    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simply convert an array to string

```
var data = [1,2,"hello"];
var data_str = data.join(",");
```

and afterwards convert the string to array in php:

```
$array = explode(",", $_REQUEST["data"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the `REQUEST` expects arrays to be passed in the following format:

```
sendData1[]=first&sendData1[]=second&sendData1[]=third
```

This is automatically converted into an array:

```
$sendData = $_REQUEST['sendData`];
echo $sendData[0];
echo $sendData[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, for the sake of simplicity, create an array holding both arrays you want to send and parse:

```
var request = Array(dates, submissions);
```

Second, make sure you're sending your request as properly formatted JSON.  In addition, when testing I recommend returning the output from the remote file in your callback to see how your data was parsed.  I recommend the following implementation, as well as sending via POST:

```
$.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   url: "NAMEOFPHPFILE.php",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify(request),
   success: function(data) {
        alert(data);        
   }
});
```

In your PHP file, get you can parse the contents of the aforementioned request into an array using the following:

```
<?php
// convert json data read from the input stream to an array
// *note* you MUST set the true flag in the json_decode() function, otherwise it will convert the data into an object
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($request);
```

You should now get an alert containing the var_dump of the array(looks messy, I know!).

This should be enough to get you started, hope it helps!

Comment: Also, this method will also work sending the request as type: "REQUEST" if that is what's preferred!